# How to return to the top page of the method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

After saving, if the saving is successful, I want it to be directed to the home page, ie the previous page. How can I do?

For example:

Save Page :   controller\method  =>    **ProcessPage\SaveProcess**

**I want to** SaveProcess method is success I go to **ProcessPage\ProcessSelect**

I method is:

ProcessPageController:

```
public string SaveProcess()
{
try
{

  //// I write savemethod.

 I want to route page method.

}

catch
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to redirect to the another MVC controller action, you could try to use RedirectToAction method.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
public string SaveProcess()
{
try
{

  //// I write savemethod.

  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

}

catch
{

}
}
```